# Mysql 5.7: Optimize query that checks for duplicates before inserting

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert, duplicates

I need you to please help me optimize this query:

```
   $sql= "INSERT INTO myTable (id, id_lang, name)
                                SELECT '" . $new_id . "', '4','" . $name. "'
                                DUAL FROM
                                WHERE NOT EXISTS(
                                SELECT 1
                                myTable FROM
                                WHERE name = '" . $name. "' AND id_lang=4
                                )
                                LIMIT 1;";
```

It works very well for what I need: insert if there is no duplicate.
But this same query is repeated in my script 7 times for 7 different tables and at the end the execution time is very high.

Any idea how to optimize it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Create UNIQUE index on fields `name` & `id_lang`. It will prevent duplicates

Comment: The expensive thing here is not how you write that query, but the search itself, as the search you have to do no matter how you express it. To optimize, you need to add indexes to make that search fast(er). (Here for at least the name, maybe name+id_lang). If you make it unique, you can let the database make sure it is unique (but that depends on your datamodel). If you already have indexes, and it is still too slow, please add details about your table.